# MKS How to list all members with their revision number on a devpath

Tags: repository, mks, mks-integrity

I am familiar with the MKS CLI, namely the `si` field, however I have a tough time honing in on the right command to get the information I need.

I am wanting to write a command against an MKS repository with

- The devpath name
- The rev number of that dev path

And the output to be

- A list of all the members of that dev path
- With each member, the specific rev of that member for that devpath rev.

I have a feeling `si rlog ...` can do this, but I can't figure out the right commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`si viewproject --project=? --devpath=?` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use si rlog if you dont want to see subproject info but you have to limit to a single revision e.g. member revision

```
si rlog -R  --project=? --devpath=? --noheaderformat --notrailerformat --revision=:member --format="{membername}\t{revision}\r\n"
```

If you are speaking of revision number of devpath I guess you mean a checkpoint within that devpath. Then you should do something like 
"--projectrevision=1.2.1.2" instead of "--devpath=?"